# jQuery image carousel settings doesn't apply to dynamic generated content (Flickr API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, flickr, dynamic-content

Hope you can help out! :)

I'm trying to created an image carousel ([Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)) with dynamic loaded content instead of static code. This dynamic content is generated using jQuery and the Flickr API.

The script you'll find below, retrieves images from a specific Flickr album and converts the data into HTML elements (image + link). Using the **$.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, item){** function I'm creating the carousel's content according the the requirements given.

The issue is, that somehow the jQuery settings from the Owl Carousel don't apply to the dynamic generated content. Using inspect element in the browser, I can see that the content is generated correctly and also some of the carousel's settings are applied to the generated content but it's not showing in the front-end: [view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP1ab.png)

Note: Converting the dynamic content to static content and inserting it inside the carousel works fine. It looks like the combination of applying a jQuery plugin on dynamic created content using another script is causing the issue.

Code snipped from the `<body>` (API key required in script):

```
<body>

<div class="owl-carousel">
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function getFlickrImages(setId) {
  var URL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/" +  // Wake up the Flickr API gods.
    "?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos" +  // Get photo from a photoset. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.htm
    "&api_key=<YOUR-API-KEY>" +  // API key. Get one here: http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/
    "&photoset_id=72157663149819061" +  // The set ID.
    "&user_id=135343422@N06" +
    "&privacy_filter=1" +  // 1 signifies all public photos.
    "&per_page=10" + // For the sake of this example I am limiting it to 20 photos.
    "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";  // Er, nothing much to explain here.

  // See the API in action here: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getPhotos
  $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
    var owner = data.photoset.owner;
    var phot_set_id = data.photoset.id;
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, item){
      // Creating the image URL. Info: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html
      var img_src = "https://farm" + item.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + item.server + "/" + item.id + "_" + item.secret + "_m.jpg";
      //var img_thumb = $("<img/>").attr("src", img_src).attr("id", item.id).css("margin", "8px");
      var link_src = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/" + owner + "/" + item.id + "/in/set-"+phot_set_id;
      var img_link =   $("<a/>").attr("href", link_src);
      var img_thumb = $('<img />').attr({src:img_src}).appendTo($('<a />').attr({href:link_src,target:"_blank"}).appendTo($('.owl-carousel')).wrap("<div></div>"));

    });
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  getFlickrImages("72157650210689192"); // Call the function!
});
</script>

<!-- OWL CAROUSEL - http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/ -->
<script src="owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
```

at the end of the function     getFlickrImages(setId).

The issue might be that the owlCarousel setting applied the first document.ready() got called and at that time your dynamic content had not generated. Thus, if you apply the owlCarousel at the end of the function getFlickrImages(setId), your dom content has already been generated and then the carousel would apply.

I fell into the same issue while using another liquid carousel(http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/), but applied the same solution as I have described above and it worked.

Hope it helps.